# Clear Logs Automatically on Asus RT-AC3200 Router

Tags: router, firmware, logfiles

Is there a way to automatically clear or delete the log files on the Asus RT-AC3200 router using something like chron?

I have setup the Reboot Scheduler but this does not clear the logs.

Firmware version is 3.0.0.4.380_4180.

Comment: This isn't possible with the default firmware

Comment: Which firmware would be required?

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet in and have a poke around?

I have an RT-AC56U and I can run a Linux shell and telnet in with my admin/xxxx credentials.

Comment: yes, in fact I use SSH.